# Can a metro app switch to last running app?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

On button click I want to go back to the last running app, just like the back button on android or Alt+Tab. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no programmatic way to the last running app specifically. However, if you know what the app is, you can activate it using a protocol handler, if it has one. E.g. If you got activated because of some flow, and you know you want to return to AppB, and AppB supports a protocol, you can use the launcher API to launch: "Appb://foo", and that app will open.

Comment: How can I launch Internet Explorer Metro? (or just the default Metro browser)

Comment: *http*://blah will launch it to a specific url.

Comment: Then I should point you to my other question: stackoverflow.com/questions/14711765